# PHP traverse array with zero values

Tags: php

I am using the following loop to traverse an array where i need both the value and the key field.

```
while ($value = current($a)) {

echo "$value ".key($a).'<br />';
next($a);
}
```

The problem is that the traversal only takes place till a '0' is encountered in the array as the while statement says.Is there any way i can traverse array with zero values(size of array varies) and get both value and key.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (which is a way more popular way to traverse arrays than this while loop).

Comment: with foreach i am not able to get key values

Comment: Of course you are. Have you had a look at the documentation?

Comment: Why you can not get key values?Did you read link as @Felix Kling  proposed? Use this: foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
{ echo "KEY : ".$key." VALUE: ".$value; }

Comment: I get it now, thanks :) . I was trying to use the similar approach with foreach to get key values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop:

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {

  echo "$value $key <br />";

}
```

it's much simpler and sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`key`](http://php.net/key) instead of `current` for the looping condition and compare its value to `null`:

> The `key()` function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, `key()` returns `NULL`.

```
while (($key = key($a)) !== null) {
    $value = value($a);
    echo "$value $key<br />";
    next($a);
}
```

But a far more convenient way would be using `foreach` instead:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value $key<br />";
}
```